# How to open pdf file stored in internal storage of app using content provider

Tags: java, android

I have a **abc.pdf** file in internal storage of app at

```
 data/data/com.example.p10documentapp/app_this_app_dir/abc.pdf
```

I first copy the file to catch directory at

```
 /data/data/com.example.p10documentapp/cache/data/data/com.example.p10documentapp/app_this_app_dir/ferguson_book.pdf
```

Then I am trying to open that abc.pdf by using **Intent.ACTION_VIEW**

I am able to open file in openFile() method in ServiceProvider class. But the file is not openning by pdf reader. Please tell me where I did wrong

MyActivity.class

```
void startInternt(){
  copyFileToInternal("abc.pdf");
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  File file = new File(activity.getCacheDir(), directory + "/" +  item.getName());
  Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile( activity,   "com.example.p10documentapp", file);
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
  try {
       activity.startActivity(intent);
  }
  catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

  private void copyFileToInternal(String name) {
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(directory + "/" + name);
        File cacheDir = activity.getCacheDir();
        File outFile = new File(cacheDir.getAbsolutePath(), name);

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buff)) > 0) {
            os.write(buff, 0, len);
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // TODO: should close streams properly here
    }
}
```

ServiceProvider.java class

```
public class ServiceProvider extends ContentProvider {
static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.example.p10documentapp";
static final String URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/this_app_dir";
static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);
private static final String PDFPATH = "public_pdfs/";

private final static String[] COLUMNS = {OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE};

static final String name = "name";
static final int uriCode = 1;
static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;

static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "this_app_dir", uriCode);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "this_app_dir/*", uriCode);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File cacheDir = getContext().getCacheDir();
    File file = new File(cacheDir,uri.getPath());
    return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
}

  @Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return "application/pdf";
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 1;
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xlm

```
  <provider
        android:name=".ServiceProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.p10documentapp"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />

    </provider>
```

filepaths.xml file

```
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <cache-path name="this_app_dir" path="." />
    </paths>
```

Comment: `android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS`. You do not need that if you have your own content provider.

Comment: `/data/data/com.example.p10documentapp/cache/data/data/com.example.p10documentapp/app_this_app_dir/ferguson_book.pdf`. That is a much to complicated directory path. Why would one twice have /data/data/com.example.p10...?

Comment: `I am trying to open that abc.pdf by using Intent.ACTION_VIEW`. Well you offer your file to an app the user chooses. You could use file.exists() to check if indeed the file exists ;hat you try to open there.

Comment: What are the values of outFile.getAbsolutePath() and the latter file.getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: I used file.exist() to check file is copied or not in cache directory, but there is no file.how can i copy file in cache directory?

Comment: Please tell all the relevant parths. And react to what i said about your path value.

Comment: I wonder why you want to copy the file first to cache. You can as well provide/serve from the original path. Please react on all my comments.

Comment: `FileProvider.getUriForFile( `. You cannot use Fileprovider as you do not use Fileprovider to serve your file. You use an extended ContentProvider. You mix up all.

Comment: so instead of getUriForFile() what I used

Comment: You should still use getUriForFile(). But not the one of FileProvider.